# Is this sentence correct please: I fear a dozen shores that I haven’t yet sailed

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I'm writing a poem and I want to convey hesitation and anxiety but I'm not sure this sentence is correct in meaning and grammar:

> I fear a dozen shores that I haven't yet sailed

Comment: You sail ships and sail *to* shores. Judgment of poetry is too subjective for me to say whether ending the line with "sailed to" works or not. You could use *sails* metaphorically as in "I fear a dozen shores that my sails have yet to visit." I like the "fear a dozen shores" part, which to me conveys anxiety, perhaps unwarranted.

Comment: As you say, this is poetry,  You have poetic licence to break the rules.

Comment: @user105719, One sails rivers, seas or oceans, and by poetic extension, "sailing shores" is certainly understandable and acceptable. " I should have been a pair of ragged claws/Scuttling across the floors of silent seas," is speaking about a crab, not a pair of pincers.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Ah, boychik, of course it's understandable and what's not acceptable in poetry? In English one sails vessels or the bodies of water upon which those vessels float. There's not a single appearance of "sailing shores" in the Ngram viewer or the Corpora of Historical or Contemporary English. Mer1em can always be the pioneer, but if she is, I think it likely her readers will be distracted by the missing final preposition. Your crab/pincer example is a synecdoche. I'm afraid I don't see how that applies.

Comment: @user105719, the phrase "sailing foreign shores" is in common use -- Google it. Academically, its "questionable", but that is *English as she is spoke*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik If you've got the google results, post 'em. In any case, it's not "sailing shores" that's in question. It's "sailed shores," or more accurately "shores ... sailed. I'm not claiming the line isn't understandable in English, but that it's distractingly inapt, especially given the distance between noun and participle. This is, of course, a subjective judgment.